# Autodesk forge Markups Core

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a markup extension in Autodesk Forge Viewer for 3D models. I have problems removing only one markup. I want to know if it is possible to show annotations in edit mode or delete markups in show mode. When I try to show markups in editing mode, I see a warning that "markups cant be showed in editing mode."
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

And to remove a specific markup from a layer after they are loaded try:

```
markExt.svgLayersMap['layerId'].markups[index].destroy()
```

Leave the editmode before showing markups - (in response to user input) you can programmatically re-enter editmode once the markups are shown:

```
ext.leaveEditMode()
ext.loadMarkups(asb,'233') //or ext.showMarkups(layerID)
ext.enterEditMode()
```

And to remove markups try:

```
ext.markups[0].destroy()
```

> show annotations in edit mode

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here? But you can create text markup programmatically - say for exp:

```
const styleObject = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.createStyle(['font-size'], window.ext);
 styleObject['font-size'] = 100;
 (new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.CreateText(window.ext, 2333, {x:20,y:20}, {x:100,y:100},'233', styleObject)).execute()
```

> or delete markups in show mode.
>   And in show mode if the markups are loaded you will need to hide on their layer level and wouldn't be able to hide a specific markup - you may fine tune this by separating them to different layers

Comment: Very good, its really that what i need, but i need to do something else.I want to delete only one markup without deleting all layer in show mode, is it possible?

Comment: I want to delete only one markup without deleting all layer in show mode? See edit ...